# extract the index of bits set in a boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, bitset

I have **dynamic bitset**  in which I'm storing randomly generated integer values.

Then I want to take blocks of n bits and check the indexes of the bits that are set to 1. At the end I'm treating the **dynamic bitset** as a sort of table. So what I want is to now if I am in the **ith** block of n bits which bits within that block are set to 1, so the indexes of the bits within the block start from 0 always. So in other words, I need to keep track of the ith block of n bits, and I also need the indexes of the bits set to 1 within that block.

**Note** I am using dynamic bitset because the size of bitset I can only know at run time, also the size of the block of n bits.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Like std::bitset, boost::dynamic_bitset does not support iterators. http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.dynamicbitset

Comment: @sehe what about bitmasking ? As I know at runtime the size of the dynamic bitset, is there a way to build the masks and then extract the bits set to 1, and know the indexes of those bits? I don´t know if my question make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C solution for the logic I think you're looking for-

```
    for (int blk_num = 0; blk_num < BLOCK_COUNT; blk_num++) {
        U32 tmp_bitmap = bitmap_arr[blk_num];
        while (tmp_bitmap > 0) {
            int next_psn = __builtin_ffs(tmp_bitmap) + blk_num * 32 - 1;
            tmp_bitmap &= (tmp_bitmap-1);
            printf("Index: %d set\n", next_psn);
        }
    }
```